# PayPal Payments Pro - Sandbox API For UK Customers

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I set up a sandbox account for PayPal a while back. I have gone to make some changes to the code, and test it in sandbox mode, but i see paypal have completely changed the interface.

I have no clue where i should be going as a UK customer, and i forgot my old sandbox passwords so i can't import it into the new developer interface..

Comment: on top of this pretty much every paypal sandbox api you go to has a broken link

Answer (score 0):

If this is the first time accessing the accounts through the new developer site, you would want to log into the new developer.paypal.com.  It will require a email address that is registered to a live PayPal account.

Once you have signed in, you will want to go to the Applications tab.
Then from here you can either choose to import your existing accounts that you had set up, but if you have forgotten them like you say.  I would suggest creating a new set of test accounts.

If you can tell me what pages you are trying to access, I can see if I have the direct link to those pages and provide you with those.

There are a few issues with the new site since its launch, and there seems to be more with IE than with other browsers.  So prior to doing anything, you may want to clear your cache and cookies before going to developer.paypal.com and also use Firefox or Chrome.
If you have cookies from the old site, it can cause issues with the new site.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chad. Do you have skype by any chance? will be easier to show that way